Calculating false negative rate for a t-test on normally distributed random variables
let's say that I have two random variables, $A$ and $B$. Both are normally distributed, with known means and standard deviations. Let's say the means are different. I am interested in calculating the false negative rate for a t-test performed on samples from these two distributions (N is number of samples, $\alpha$ is the type 1 error rate). One simple way, is to perform Monte Carlo simulation. Specifically, I could sample from both $A$ and $B$, and then perform a t-test to calculate the P value. If the P value is greater than $\alpha$, I would count that as a false negative. I could then perform this many times, say M, and sum up the number of false positives and divide by M to calculate the false negative rate. My question is: is there an analytical approach to calculate the value instead of this approach? Any help would be greatly appreciated

There is, but CPU cycles are cheaper than they've ever been and the simulation approach is much more flexible when you go beyond the simplest textbook cases. Related, is this a self-study question?

I'm not sure what a self-study question is exactly, but it's something I am personally interested in doing, yes

I should probably have included the tag link; have a look at its description.

Yes, there is an analytical approach and it can be evaluated numerically and in closed form in terms of the non-central t distribution.
